# Javascript Call Function Simple Help Needed

Tags: javascript, windows-8

@TheSystem here is the code have a look and solve it

```
<div class="fragment groupeditemspage">
    <header aria-label="Header content" role="banner">
        <button class="win-backbutton" aria-label="Back" disabled></button>
        <h1 class="titlearea win-type-ellipsis">
            <span class="pagetitle"><b>OvalFox </b>News Reader</span>
        </h1>
    </header>
    <section aria-label="Main content" role="main">
    <progress class="win-ring withText" id="loadingIndicator"></progress>
        <div class="groupeditemslist" aria-label="List of groups" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.ListView" data-win-options="{ selectionMode: 'none' }"></div>
    </section>
</div>
```

Above is html code, it contain progress tag if you see, it show progress bar when I start windows 8 application, and progress bar keep runs and hide as soon content is load with no issue, once I click on any item to see its detail page, its open with no issue, however as soon I click on back button which function is this

```
navigated: function () {
                // Do application specific on-navigated work here
                var backButton = this.pageElement.querySelector("header[role=banner] .win-backbutton");
                if (backButton) {
                    backButton.onclick = function () { nav.back(); };

                    if (nav.canGoBack) {
                        backButton.removeAttribute("disabled");
                    } else {
                        backButton.setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
                    }
                }
            },
```

the progress bar appears in main page and not hide again even content is default loaded at the page

here is the javascript code of progress bar

```
for (var n = 0; n < items.length; n++) {
        var article = {};
        // Get the title, author, and date published.
        article.title = items[n].querySelector("title").textContent;
        article.author = items[n].querySelector("creator").textContent;
        article.date = items[n].querySelector("pubDate").textContent;
        var thumbs = items[n].querySelectorAll("content");
        article.content = items[n].querySelector("description").textContent;
        var staticContent = toStaticHTML(items[n].querySelector("description").textContent);
        var progressBar = document.getElementById("loadingIndicator").style.display = 'none';
        progressBar.value = 1;
        // Process the content so that it displays nicely.

        if (thumbs.length > 1) {
            article.thumbnail = thumbs[thumbs.length - 1].attributes.getNamedItem("url").textContent;

        }
        else {
            var firstindex = article.content.indexOf("<img");
            if (firstindex !== 1) {
                var secondindex = article.content.indexOf("src=", firstindex) + 5;
                var thirdindex = article.content.indexOf("\"", secondindex);
                article.thumbnail = article.content.slice(secondindex, thirdindex);
            }
        }
```

above code contain following section of code

```
var progressBar = document.getElementById("loadingIndicator").style.display = 'none';
        progressBar.value = 1;
```

above code is actual code which use to hide progress bar as soon content it loaded, however this function not works once back button clicked

Hope to get help in this detailed and complex code from you @TheSystem and others

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+hide+element

Comment: if you cant help, you should not comment, if i m getting help then their is a reason of getting help!!!! if you want me to post a tuff code here i m facing then i can let me know, so i hope you will find the issue for me from the big code....

Comment: the system have a look into question as answer i posted below and solve my issue

Comment: @thesystem, it is now solve it ?

Comment: @thesystem have a look into comment in james section

Answer (score 2):

This code doesn't do what you think:

```
var progressBar = document.getElementById("loadingIndicator").style.display = 'none';
progressBar.value = 1;
```

You want

```
var progressBar = document.getElementById("loadingIndicator");
progressBar.style.display = 'none';
progressBar.value = 1;
```

Comment: have a look into my below code it is detail question in which i m getting issue for what i did posted above small code to get help and solve out issue my self

Comment: You still did not read question correctly, the code i provided is working same thing the one you provided solution. When windows 8 app load, progress bar show and hide as soon content is retrive from rss feed, once i click on any item to see its detail page, it goes to detail page, once click on back button which funtion i provided above, the progress bar again appears, actually

Comment: <progress class="win-ring withText" id="loadingIndicator"></progress>

Comment: this is the code of progress in html, which show loading progress, javascript code only use to hide it, above javascript code only load once when windows start, when i click on detail item and click back button page, above javascript code not execute only html progress bar execute, so what is solution for that ?

Comment: I would start putting some alerts in the code that displays the progress bar and try to pinpoint what is failing when you hit the back button.  Is items.length == 0 maybe?

Comment: not sure about it, complete portion of code i already added in question, actually content is retreiving in site is from rss feed, so progrss bar hide with no issue as soon content load, however when i go to detail of any item and click on back button to come to main screen where all content is preloaded, there progress bar also showing